# Need help killing psuedo terminals

Tags: ubuntu, cron

I have a ubuntu web server that uses a chron job to connected to a third party sftp, pull a file and disconnect. This was working for a few weeks and has stopped.

I tried to manually SSH into the sftp from my webserver and I got the following error:

> shell request failed on channel 0

This lead me to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27021641/how-to-fix-request-failed-on-channel-0

This gave me lsof /dev/pts/* to see what open files I have

```
sudo lsof /dev/pts/*
COMMAND  PID   USER       FD   TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
bash    1513 ubuntu    0u   CHR  136,0      0t0    3 /dev/pts/0
bash    1513 ubuntu    1u   CHR  136,0      0t0    3 /dev/pts/0
bash    1513 ubuntu    2u   CHR  136,0      0t0    3 /dev/pts/0
bash    1513 ubuntu  255u   CHR  136,0      0t0    3 /dev/pts/0
sudo    1670   root    0u   CHR  136,0      0t0    3 /dev/pts/0
sudo    1670   root    1u   CHR  136,0      0t0    3 /dev/pts/0
sudo    1670   root    2u   CHR  136,0      0t0    3 /dev/pts/0
lsof    1671   root    0u   CHR  136,0      0t0    3 /dev/pts/0
lsof    1671   root    1u   CHR  136,0      0t0    3 /dev/pts/0
lsof    1671   root    2u   CHR  136,0      0t0    3 /dev/pts/0
```

If I'm understanding this correctly I have 255 instances of a psuedo terminal open from my script. As such if I'm not completely wrong I have two problems. One is that I need to close those so that I can get my code working again and secondly I need to fix my code such that it closes this properly.